# ZXing barcode scan app error on camera launch

Tags: android, barcode, zxing, google-search

I'm using ZXing library in Android app, the app is actually from Tek Eye. I've made modifications and it works great, but on some Android devices when I hit the scan button to launch device camera and begin scanning the application gives an error and quits. The error is:

> Unfortunately, Google Search has stopped

This is the log from eclipse:

```
12-17 13:38:33.396: I/System.out(2975): debugger has settled (1496)
12-17 13:38:33.411: D/dalvikvm(2975): open_cached_dex_file : /data/app/biz.tekeye.scanbarcode-2.apk /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@biz.tekeye.scanbarcode-2.apk@classes.dex
12-17 13:38:33.417: D/ActivityThread(2975): BIND_APPLICATION handled : 0 / AppBindData{appInfo=ApplicationInfo{414f0f58 biz.tekeye.scanbarcode}}
12-17 13:38:33.495: D/ActivityThread(2975): ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{414f56b8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@414f1c00 {biz.tekeye.scanbarcode/biz.tekeye.scanbarcode.Main}}
12-17 13:38:33.514: D/ActivityThread(2975): ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{414f56b8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@414f1c00 {biz.tekeye.scanbarcode/biz.tekeye.scanbarcode.Main}}
12-17 13:38:33.570: V/InputMethodManager(2975): onWindowFocus: null softInputMode=288 first=true flags=#8010100
12-17 13:38:33.571: V/InputMethodManager(2975): Starting input: view=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@414fcf78
12-17 13:38:33.572: V/InputMethodManager(2975): Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@41512238 ic=null
12-17 13:38:33.573: V/InputMethodManager(2975): START INPUT: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@414fcf78 ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@41512238 controlFlags=#104
12-17 13:38:33.578: D/dalvikvm(2975): threadid=11: interp stack at 0x523ae000
12-17 13:38:33.579: D/jdwp(2975): sendRequest : Len=0x1D
12-17 13:38:33.579: V/InputMethodManager(2975): Starting input: Bind result=InputBindResult{null com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME #43}
12-17 13:38:33.581: D/jdwp(2975): processIncoming
12-17 13:38:33.581: D/jdwp(2975): handlePacket : cmd=0x9, cmdSet=0x9, len=0x13, id=0x2BF, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
12-17 13:38:33.584: D/jdwp(2975): processIncoming
12-17 13:38:33.585: D/jdwp(2975): handlePacket : cmd=0x5, cmdSet=0xB, len=0x13, id=0x2C0, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
12-17 13:38:33.587: D/jdwp(2975): processIncoming
12-17 13:38:33.587: D/jdwp(2975): handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0x9, len=0x13, id=0x2C1, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
12-17 13:38:33.588: D/jdwp(2975): processIncoming
12-17 13:38:33.588: D/jdwp(2975): handlePacket : cmd=0x2, cmdSet=0x9, len=0x1B, id=0x2C2, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x10
12-17 13:38:33.589: D/jdwp(2975): processIncoming
12-17 13:38:33.589: D/jdwp(2975): handlePacket : cmd=0x4, cmdSet=0xB, len=0x13, id=0x2C3, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
12-17 13:38:33.590: D/jdwp(2975): processIncoming
12-17 13:38:33.590: D/jdwp(2975): handlePacket : cmd=0x4, cmdSet=0xB, len=0x13, id=0x2C4, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
12-17 13:38:33.641: V/InputMethodManager(2975): Starting input: view=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@414fcf78
12-17 13:38:33.642: V/InputMethodManager(2975): Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@41513e88 ic=null
12-17 13:38:33.722: D/jdwp(2975): processIncoming
12-17 13:38:33.722: D/jdwp(2975): handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xB, len=0x13, id=0x2C5, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
12-17 13:38:33.723: D/jdwp(2975): processIncoming
12-17 13:38:33.723: D/jdwp(2975): handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xB, len=0x13, id=0x2C6, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
12-17 13:38:42.290: I/SurfaceTextureClient(2975): [STC::queueBuffer] this:0x518e7480, api:2, last queue time elapsed :8651 ms
12-17 13:38:42.290: I/SurfaceTextureClient(2975): [0x518e7480] frames:2, duration:8.651000, fps:0.231168
12-17 13:38:42.301: V/Provider/Setting(2975): from db cache, name = sound_effects_enabled value = 0
12-17 13:38:42.352: D/ActivityThread(2975): ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{414f56b8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@414f1c00 {biz.tekeye.scanbarcode/biz.tekeye.scanbarcode.Main}}
12-17 13:38:42.399: D/ActivityThread(2975): ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@414f1c00
12-17 13:38:43.429: D/ActivityThread(2975): SEND_RESULT handled : 0 / ResultData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@414f1c00 results[ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=0, data=null}]}
12-17 13:38:43.430: D/ActivityThread(2975): ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{414f56b8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@414f1c00 {biz.tekeye.scanbarcode/biz.tekeye.scanbarcode.Main}}
12-17 13:38:43.431: D/ActivityThread(2975): ACT-RESUME_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@414f1c00
12-17 13:38:43.441: V/InputMethodManager(2975): onWindowFocus: null softInputMode=288 first=true flags=#8010100
12-17 13:38:43.441: V/InputMethodManager(2975): Starting input: view=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@414fcf78
12-17 13:38:43.442: V/InputMethodManager(2975): Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@415191a8 ic=null
12-17 13:38:43.443: V/InputMethodManager(2975): START INPUT: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@414fcf78 ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@415191a8 controlFlags=#104
12-17 13:38:43.446: V/InputMethodManager(2975): Starting input: Bind result=InputBindResult{com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy@41519d38 com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME #45}
12-17 13:38:56.759: I/SurfaceTextureClient(2975): [STC::queueBuffer] this:0x518e7480, api:2, last queue time elapsed :13250 ms
12-17 13:38:56.759: I/SurfaceTextureClient(2975): [0x518e7480] frames:3, duration:13.360000, fps:0.224543
12-17 13:38:56.985: V/Provider/Setting(2975): from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled value = 0
12-17 13:38:57.090: D/ActivityThread(2975): ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{414f56b8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@414f1c00 {biz.tekeye.scanbarcode/biz.tekeye.scanbarcode.Main}}
12-17 13:38:57.133: D/ActivityThread(2975): ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@414f1c00
12-17 13:38:58.317: D/ActivityThread(2975): ACT-DESTROY_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@414f1c00
```

The error occurred on Android devices version 4.1.1 (custom build from manufacturer IconBit) and 4.3.1 (custom build from manufacturer DNS). However, I've tried on several devices of version 4.1.1 and 4.3.2 and 4.2.1 and the application works. I'm not sure what the problem is and what Google Search has to do with the app.

The piece of code calling the intent is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
switch(arg0.getId()){
case R.id.butQR:
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);    //Barcode Scanner to scan for us
    break;
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that some android devices did not have zxing library and I had to install barcode scanner from zxing team for my application to work on the devices that do not have the library.